# Lark : how to pick only some patterns

Tags: parsing, text-parsing, lark-parser

I would like to extract from a text file only some structured patterns.

example, in the text below:

```
   blablabla 
   foo FUNC1 ; blabliblo blu
```

I would like to isolate only 'foo FUNC1 ;'.

I was trying to use lark parser with the following parser

```
foo=Lark('''
  start:  statement*
  statement: foo 
           | anything
  anything : /.+/
  foo : "foo" ID ";"
  ID : /_?[a-z][_a-z0-9]*/i
  %import common.WS
  %import common.NEWLINE
  %ignore WS
  %ignore NEWLINE
''',
parser="lalr" ,
propagate_positions=True)
```

But the token 'anything' captures all. Is there a way to make it not greedy ? So that the token 'foo' can capture the given pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with priorities.

For `parser="lalr"`, Lark supports priorities on terminals. So you could move `"foo"` into its own terminal and then assign that terminal a higher priority than the `anything` terminal (which has default priority `1`):

```
  foo : FOO ID ";"
  FOO.2: "foo"
```

Parsing your example string then results in:

```
start
  statement
    anything    blablabla 
  statement
    foo
      foo
      FUNC1
  statement
    anything    blabliblo blu
```

For `parser="earley"`, Lark supports priorities on rules, so you could use:

```
  foo.2 : "foo" ID ";"
```

Parsing your example string then results in:

```
start
  statement
    anything    blablabla 
  statement
    foo FUNC1
  statement
    anything     blabliblo blu
```